# Combining D3 and Jquery in different tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have been trying to combine jQuery and D3.js to show different chrts in different tabs. I have in gneral two tabs and in the first one I want to show a cart and in the second one I would like to present a simple (later I would to show a chart).

The final results is that I have got the the tabs and the chrts are shown below. I was wondering whether I need to use AJAX in that case?

Here is my code:

`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="generic.css">

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  function draw(data){
    "use strict";       
    d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
            .attr("class", "chart")
        .selectAll("div.line")
        .data(data.cash)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
            .attr("class", "line");

    d3.selectAll("div.line")
        .append("div")
            .attr("class","label")
            .text(function(d){return d.name});

    d3.selectAll("div.line")
        .append("div")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .style("width", function (d) {return d.count/100 + "px"})                   
            .text(function (d){return Math.round(d.count)});            
  }

   $(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
         <li><a href="#tabs-1">Data</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-2">Text</a></li>    
       </ul>

     <div id="tabs-1">
        xx1
        <script>
           d3.json("data/plaza_traffic.json", draw);    
    </script>             
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       zz
     </div>  
   </div>

</body>
</html>`

Any help would be much appreciated!
Andi

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is your question

Comment: When I run this file, then the graph which I want to show does not appear in "tabs-1". At first the menue appears and below the graph is displayed. But I would like to have the graph to be displayed in the menu of tabs-1.

Comment: What's your data look like?  Post a sample of `plaza_traffic.json`

Comment: here is an extract of my data:   {  "cash": [
        {
            "count": 26774.09756097561, 
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Robert F. Kennedy Bridge Bronx Plaza"
        }, 
        {
            "count": 18612.77618364419, 
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Robert F. Kennedy Bridge Manhattan Plaza"
        }
    ] }